# Select certain items from array of objects to create new array in Typescript?

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, for-loop

I would like to create an array of strings out of a separate array object.

```
export interface box{
    image: string,
    link: string,
    button_name: string,
    info: string, 
    description: string
}

export const BOX: box[] = [
    {image: 'image here', link: 'google.com',
    button_name: 'name', info: 'some information', description: "a description"
    },

    {image: 'image here again', link: 'another google.com',
    button_name: 'another name', info: 'some more information', description: "another description"
    },
]
```

Essentially I would like to create a new array out of this existing information, but it would just be an array of info. I am unsure how to implement this in typescript. I have tried using the ForEach function like so:

```
infos: string[] = BOX.forEach(element => element.info);
```

but this will return me an error saying that

```
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'string[]'
```

How can I create an array of strings that consist of just the info fields of my existing array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the map function on the BOX-array. It will return a new array with what you put in the arrow function. If you only want the element's info, you can do this

```
infos: string[] = BOX.map(element => element.info);
```

The above has an implicit return statement, and is the shorthand for the same function below.

```
infos: string[] = BOX.map(element => {
   return element.info;
});
```

[Here are some more information about the topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: And just a wee shorter and perhaps a little funner, you could do `Box.map(({ info }) => info)` or even `Box.map(({ info }) => ({ info }))` if you want it typed as `infos: { info: string }[]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
const infos = BOX.map(element => element.info);
```

Comment: Explanation and links to documentation would make this a much better answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
infos: string[] = BOX.forEach(element => element.info);
```

`Array.prototype.forEach` returns `undefined` from the definition.
It only executes the provided function once for each array element.

So in your case, you need to use `Array.prototype.map` function to map `info` param for each element.

```
const infos = BOX.map(el => el.info);
```